# How to insert a delay in response with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a fast-cgi application that do some work at http://myapp.com/do?arg=x. The job may take a few minutes. So I want to keep redirecting the users to the same URL (with 307) until the job is done, and serve the results with a 200 OK. I would like to slow done the response rate, so that it takes the client 30s (for example) to receive a 307. Obviously, I don't want to do in the back-end because I need to handle other jobs. It is possible to tell nginx to insert a delay, or rate limit the response for a particular URL?

I've looked at limit_req, but I don't think it can be used to rate limit unique URLS (http://myapp.com/do?arg=x versus http://myapp.com/do?arg=y) but rather unique IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've settle for this solution:

1. Send 307 with the headers:

   - Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   - Content-Length: X
   - Cache-Control: no-cache
   - Pragma: no-cache
   - write 1-byte chunk every second for X seconds
2. 200 OK with the result

Answer (score 3):

You might want to restructure your application to better handle the situation. I would have two scripts: one is the web page the user hits. The second is a back end script that dose the job.

Script two can be a daemon, or you can use non-blocking forking if your environment supports it from script one. Script one should initiate the job in script two, then push data to the user using something like [EventStream](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) (or WebSockets, although thats a major overkill here) updating them of the status. You can send a 200 or some other indication when your done.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However, I'm targeting thin clients through an API rather than web browsers